# Chrome print aliasing with min-height ion-inputs

Tags: css, google-chrome, ionic4

I'm using `@media print` styling to condense a bulky page of `ion-input`s to reduce the page count by 15 pages.
[image: chrome print bulky screenshot]

Print to pdf (print preview and opening the saved pdf) looks good in Firefox v63,
[image: firefox print condensed screenshot]

but in Chrome v70 it produces aliasing or entire line absence when I set `min-height`, regardless of chrome page margins of None or Default. I have also seen it drop the id, description, subitem name, or the price line if they fall in the page break gap.
[image: chrome print condensed aliasing screenshot]

Is there a way to prevent Chrome from aliasing or dropping lines around its automatic page wraps/breaks?

--

Code:

```
@media print {
    ion-item, .item-inner, .input-wrapper, ion-input, input  {
        min-height: 23px !important; // causes line aliasing
        height: 24px !important;
        max-height: 25px !important;
        line-height: 26px !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<ion-card *ngFor="let eachCard of myCards">
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-2>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="eachCard.id"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-11>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="eachCard.description1"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="eachCard.description2></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="eachCard.description3"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <div *ngFor="let eachSubitem of eachCard.subitems">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-1></ion-col>
      <ion-col col-5>
          <ion-item>
              <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="eachSubitem.name"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-5>
          <ion-item>
              <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="eachSubitem.altName"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-1></ion-col>
      <ion-col col-3>
          <ion-item>
              <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="eachubitem.price"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-7>
          <ion-item>
              <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="eachSubitem.unit"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </div>
</ion-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```css
ion-item  {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```